How can I generate observations of a lognormal distribution in NetLogo?
I have the values of parameters of the lognormal distribution (mu=1.23 and sigma=0.32) that characterize the income of a population. In Netlogo, how can I generate observations of the income and then assign them to an attribute of a turtle?

Another alternative is the stats extension, which contains the log-normal distribution (and several others).  It can be loaded simply by adding it to your extensions command.

I would say you have two options:
Option 1: Implement your own reporter for a log-normal distribution. You can define a reporter with to-report followed by the name (e.g. random-log-normal). There you could draw a random number and transform it to a log-normal distribution. I'm not familiar with the math, but I guess that's not a big deal.
Option 2: Use the R available function. You can use R code by using the r or SimpleR extension. Here is an example with the SimpleR extension:
extensions [sr]

to setup
  sr:setup
end

to-report random-log-normal [mu sigma]
  sr:set "mu" mu
  sr:set "sigma" sigma
  report sr:runresult "rlnorm(1, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma)"
end

